# How can I unstate(delete) and state(create) a cookie in single request in hapijs?

Tags: node.js, cookies, hapi.js

I just  want to do two operations in a single request.
1) Delete an older cookie for the entire domain and not just for a given path
2) Create a new cookie for the entire domain, subdomain and ports.
For deleting  a cookie,I tried "unstate" but the cookie does not get removed from the browser.

```
  "cookieOptions": {
    "ttl": 315569260000,
    "isSecure": true,
    "isHttpOnly": true,
    "isSameSite":false,
    "path":"/",
    "encoding": "base64json",
    "clearInvalid": false, // remove invalid cookies
    "strictHeader": true // don't allow violations of RFC 6265
}
```

sample of cookies options from my config

```
handler: function (request, reply) {
reply('ok').unstate(“olderCookies”).state(“newCookies”,Config.get('cookieOptions'));
}
```